# Creating different label styles for different polygon classes using QGIS?

Tags: labeling, qgis-2

I'm new to QGIS 2. I have a polygon shape with two classes, and I want to set different labeling style and different "Scale-based visibility" but I don't get how the expression works.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Style tab of layer properties dialogue. Select rule-based option from the dropdown list. Here you can define how polygons should be rendered (see image below)[image]

I defined two styles, one for polygons having id = 1 and the other for polygons having id = 2. Their min. and max. scale differ, as you can see in the picture.

For the labels probably the easiest way is using data-defined properties on Labels tab. See how it works [here](http://anitagraser.com/2013/06/04/data-defined-properties-in-qgis-2-0/).

Here you can see both polygons visible as they fit between min. and max. scale (I changed the values, the princip is the same though).

[image]

And here you see just the blue one because I zoomed out far beyond the max. scale of the green polygon.

[image]

If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.