# Creating different label styles for different attribute in layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I would like to create labels with different shapes in the same layer (like ellipse and triangle).

Is it possible?

I just read [Creating different label styles for different polygon classes using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77216), but it's for the style.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE! Please take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and learn how to write good questions. Give more info and share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have shapes in your label. It is up to you to display both shapes and text, or just shapes (or most commonly, just text).

Before going the `label` way, it is worth considering using a `style`. You could even have multiple style per layer, one rendering the data as polygon and another one rendering it as a point - with the shape of your choice.

To have different shapes in the layer **labels**, you would need different labeling rules, similar to the style rules.

Open your layer label panel, select `Rule-based labeling` and create as many rule as required (one per shape, with the appropriate filter like `my_var = 1`

[image]

If you just want to show the shape, then you would write the text transparently.

[image]

For the shapes, you would use the `background` options. For the ellipse, it is pre-defined so you can just select the shape name.

[image]

For the triangle or for more complex shapes, you would use an SVG file. Select the SVG option, then browse to the `app symbols`, `backgrounds` and select the triangle.

In both case, you should put a `fixed size` if the shape is not related to the text length. Similarly, you can change the color.

[image]